# Strange bug with an self made Position variable in Java

Tags: java, debugging

I have a really strange bug in my code. Wich I have never seen before.
`zkpos.x++;`
It occurs in this line.
When the `zkpos.x` is raised by one there is also another variable raised by one. 
which is called `kpos.x`.
`kpos`and`zkpos`are Position variables.

```
    public class Position {
    int x, y;
    public Position(int nx, int ny)
    {x=nx;
     y=ny;}}
```

The full code is this.

```
    while(c<z.mRange)
{
    kpos.y=kpos.y - 1;
    tpos[index]=kpos;
    //System.out.println("tpos["+index+"]: " +tpos[index].x+", "+tpos[index].y);
    c++;
    index++;
    zc = c;
    zkpos=kpos;

        while(zc<z.mRange)
        {
            //System.out.println();
            //System.out.println(kpos.x);
            zkpos.x++;

            //System.out.println(kpos.x);
            tpos[index]=zkpos;
            //System.out.println("tpos["+index+"]: " +tpos[index].x+", "+tpos[index].y+ " "+kpos.x);
            index++;
            zc++;
        }

}
```

I hope someone has a solution to my strange bug.
Thx for helping.

Comment: Hint: give your variables names that mean something. Instead of 1 character based abbreviations.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't strange at all; it's perfectly normal.

```
zkpos=kpos;
```

This line makes `zkpos` and `kpos` point to the same `Position` object.  Modifications made to one will be seen in the other, because there's only one position.

Instead, make `zkpos` a *copy* of `kpos`.  You're going to have to make a *new* `Position` object and set its properties to be equal to `kpos`.  A common strategy is to make a copy constructor.

Comment: They are two different Positions

Comment: `Position kpos = new Position(0,0); 
 Position zkpos = new Position(0,0);`

Comment: But you are making them point to the same instance.

Comment: @Zoromonk: They might _start_ as two different positions, but once you write `zkpos = kpos`, they aren't anymore.

Comment: @Zoromonk Not after `zkpos=kpos`.  Both variables now refer to the same object, and the one previously referred to by `zkpos` is lost (unless there's another reference to it somehwere).

Comment: Thx for your help.